# Why is jasmine/karma on IE 11 only rendering the 2nd data bound Angular object?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

This is a really weird situation. We've developed a suite of tests that run in Chrome, but we decided to unleash them on IE 11 as well. There is one test that I cannot seem to get to work within the suite of tests. It's testing a directive.

The directive template looks like this:

```
<div class="flex center-v margined-left-double margined-top-double" ng-switch on="cancelHasRef()">
    <button class="ui primary button" type="submit" ng-click="primaryAction()" pb-disable="disableAction()" tabindex="{{primaryTabIndex}}">{{primaryText}}</button>
    <button ng-if="showAddAnother()" class="ui secondary button" type="submit" ng-click="secondaryAction()" pb-disable="disableAction()" tabindex="{{secondaryTabIndex}}">Save & Add Another</button>
    <a ng-switch-default class="basic button margined-left" ui-sref="{{cancelRef}}" tabindex="{{cancelTabIndex}}">{{cancelText}}</a>
    <a ng-switch-when="false" class="basic button margined-left" ng-click="cancelAction()" tabindex="{{cancelTabIndex}}">{{cancelText}}</a>
</div>
```

The values are set in the link function of the directive:

```
scope: {
                cancelRef: '@',
                primaryAction: '&',
                secondaryAction: '&',
                disableAction: '&',
                cancelAction: '&',
                cancelText: '@',
                primaryTabIndex: '=',
                secondaryTabIndex: '=',
                cancelTabIndex: '=',
                primaryText: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.primaryText = scope.primaryText || 'Save';
                scope.cancelText = scope.cancelText || 'Cancel';
```

The test that is failing:

```
        describe('Add button', function () {
            beforeEach(function () {
                element = $compile('<action-items cancel-ref="customer.details" disable-action="disableSubmit()"></action-items>')($scope);
                $scope.$digest();
                button = $(element).find('button.ui.primary')[0];
                console.log('Button', button);
                console.log('Div', $(button).parent());
            });

            it('Should be labeled Save', function () {
                expect(button.textContent).toEqual('Save');
            });
        });
```

The error is that it expected {{primaryText}} to equal Save. So it appears as if the binding is not happening.

If I run this test by itself, using `ddescribe` or just excluding all other files from my suite, it passes.

If I run this test with other tests, it starts to fail. That seems to indicate that a previous test is causing problems.

I modified my template and just had it place the text of `{{cancelText}}` and `{{primaryText}}` at the top of the div:

```
<div class="flex center-v margined-left-double margined-top-double" ng-switch on="cancelHasRef()">
  {{primaryText}}
  {{cancelText}}
```

Once I do that, my test starts passing. If I output what's in the div, what I see is:

{{primaryText}}
  Cancel

If I swap the order, what I see is:

```
<div class="flex center-v margined-left-double margined-top-double" ng-switch on="cancelHasRef()">
  {{cancelText}}
  Save
```

It appears that the first data bound item is not getting rendered. This is only happening on IE11, not on Chrome and not on FireFox.

Does anyone have an idea on what might be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

We're still not exactly sure *why* this is happening, but we have found a resolution.

We had added a gulp task to add all our templates to `$templateCache`.  We also had used `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor` and had a line at the top to bring in our template, e.g. `beforeEach(module('myModule', 'my.template.html'));`

Once we removed the templates from the `beforeEach` and removed the dependency on `karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor` and used just our `templates.js` (instead of both `templates.js` and the `html2js` pre-processor) everything ran smoothly.